# Calling abstract and derived tt template in VS extension

Tags: c#, t4, visual-studio-extensions

I´m working on extension for VS. It should map database object thru TT templates. Templates can be made by users of extension. Only thing is, that have to inherit abstract template, whitch is part of extension. I found a recomandation on Microsoft documentation to call transformation in VS extension this way: [Invoking Text Transformation in a VS Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/invoking-text-transformation-in-a-vs-extension?view=vs-2017) It works fine, for dummy template, like this:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>

<#
Generate(new List<string> {"AAA","BBB","CCC"},  "666");
#>
<#+ 
public void Generate(List<string> inputList, string tableName)
{
#>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace BBB 

public class <#= tableName #>
{
    <#+
    foreach(var t in inputList)
    {
    #>
        /// <summary>
        /// <#= t #>
        /// </summary>
    <#+
    }
    #>
}
<#+
}
#>
```

And code:

```
Generate("..\\..\\Templates\\TextTemplate.tt");

public void Generate(string filePath)
    {
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = ServiceProvider;
        ITextTemplating t4 = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(STextTemplating)) as ITextTemplating;
        T4Callback cb = new T4Callback();
        string result = t4.ProcessTemplate(filePath, File.ReadAllText(filePath), cb);
        string resultFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)) + "_gen" + cb.fileExtension;
        File.WriteAllText(resultFileName, result, cb.outputEncoding);
    }


public class T4Callback : ITextTemplatingCallback
{
    public List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();
    public string fileExtension = ".cs";
    public Encoding outputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    public void ErrorCallback(bool warning, string message, int line, int column)
    { errorMessages.Add(message); }

    public void SetFileExtension(string extension)
    { fileExtension = extension; }

    public void SetOutputEncoding(Encoding encoding, bool fromOutputDirective)
    { outputEncoding = encoding; }
}
```

But it doesn't work with abstract template. If I have abstract template:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>

<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="FakeIn" #> 

<#   
this.PushIndent("  ");  

//Generate method
Generate(InputData); 

//Save method
SaveOutput(OutputFileName);

this.PopIndent();  
#>  

<#+ 
#region Properties
public string OutputFileName { get; set; }
public InPutClass InputData { get; set; }
#endregion

#region Override method
protected virtual void Generate(InPutClass input) { }
#endregion

#region Non-Override method
protected void SaveOutput(string outputFileName) 
{
    string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(outputFileName);
    File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString()); 
    this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(0, this.GenerationEnvironment.Length);
}
#endregion

#region Data classes
public class InPutClass
{
    public List<string> InputList { get; set; }
    public string InputTableName { get; set; }
}
#endregion
#>
```

and derived one like this:

```
<#@ template language="C#" inherits="AbstractTemplate" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>

<#
InputData = new InPutClass{ InputList = new List<string>{"AAA","BBB","CCC"}, InputTableName = "abc" };
OutputFileName = "..\\..\\Templates\\file2.cs";
base.TransformText();  
#>

<#+ 
protected override void Generate(InPutClass input)
{
#>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using ABEL.CORE.TypeComponents;
using ABEL.DAL.Attributes;
using Protos.Data;

namespace BBB 

public class <#= input.InputTableName #>
{
    <#+
    foreach(var t in input.InputList)
    {
    #>
        /// <summary>
        /// <#= t #>
        /// </summary>
    <#+
    }
    #>
}
<#+
}
#>
```

If I call method Generate result is:

ErrorGeneratingOutput

- Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'AbstractTemplate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'InPutClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()': no suitable method found to override
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation.Generate(InPutClass)': no suitable method found to override
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: The name 'InputData' does not exist in the current context
- Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'InPutClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: The name 'OutputFileName' does not exist in the current context
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'GenerationEnvironment' and no extension method 'GenerationEnvironment' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'GenerationEnvironment' and no extension method 'GenerationEnvironment' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Compiling transformation: 'GeneratedTextTransformation' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So for me it looks like, the templates don´t know nothing about youselfs. Because when I have both of them as a part of solution and call just classic template template.TransformText(); everything is ok.

I also try some combination of PreprocessingTemplate, like this:

```
   GenerateAbstract("\\..\\..\\Templates2\\DerivedTemplate2.tt");
   public void GenerateAbstract(string filePath)
    {
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = ServiceProvider;
        ITextTemplating t4 = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(STextTemplating)) as ITextTemplating;

        T4Callback cb = new T4Callback();
        string[] reference;
        string abstractTemplatePath = "..\\..\\Templates2\\AbstractTemplate.tt";

        string abstractTemplatePreprocessing = t4.PreprocessTemplate(abstractTemplatePath, File.ReadAllText(abstractTemplatePath), cb, "AbstractTemplate", "AbstractTemplating.Templates2", out reference);
        string derived2TemplatePreprocessing = t4.PreprocessTemplate(filePath, File.ReadAllText(filePath), cb, "DerivedTemplate2", "AbstractTemplating.Templates2", out reference);

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine("..\\..\\Templates2", "AbstractTemplate.cs"), abstractTemplatePreprocessing, cb.outputEncoding);
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine("..\\..\\Templates2", "DerivedTemplate2.cs"), derived2TemplatePreprocessing, cb.outputEncoding);

        string result = t4.ProcessTemplate("..\\..\\Templates2\\AbstractTemplate.cs", derived2TemplatePreprocessing, cb);

        string resultFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)) + "_gen" + cb.fileExtension;
        // Write the processed output to file:
        File.WriteAllText(resultFileName, result, cb.outputEncoding);
        // Append any error messages:
        if (cb.errorMessages.Count > 0)
        {
            File.AppendAllLines(resultFileName, cb.errorMessages);
        }
    }
```

But in this case is result C# code for DerivedTemplate2 : AbstractTemplate, something like when the template is part of solution and solution is builded.

So finally my question is possible to call abstract and derived template somehow this way? And if is, can you please give a example how to achive this. Thank you

Comment: Could you explain how your extension should work? 
It should generate both "Abstract" and "Derrived" templates?

Comment: No, in derived template is method Generate() that have to be inherit by the users templates. So the output should be a one file. In article are simplified templates in extension is in abstract template logic, that connect to DB and obtain data for generation. And in users templates should be definition how can be the data from db processed.

Answer (score 0):

It is only an opinion but on your described topic:

1. do not hide your template from your user (put it to the solution together with generated code) - the method that VS MVC-Entity-Extension do it - is  opposite - but MS is wrong in this case (and low popularity of codegeneration in MS world is evidence for this). If you have to generate 100 files, create 100 templates also. Or **one** template that generate hundred classes in **one** file.
2. do not mix codegeneration and realization inheritance  - they are orthogonal to each other. First is for publish "everything" to user in form user "allow to change everything", second is for hiding details (and why you should hide details if you want to provide for your user ' you are able to change everything' functionality)?

Comment: Thanks for advises, but:
1) template is not hide, is copied into solution where is extension used, together with templates, that select user. See picture bellow:
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q0QIJ1nS7k_A8j2vxeB0Sga759w-NOBq)

json config contains list of db object that should be generated and connection to database, config is read by abstract template and prepare data for user template and user teplate generates *.cs classes

Comment: 2) User can not change everything, he can change only how the data from db will be wrapeed in his method, not how he obtain data. Abstract template here is in mean, that user have to override Generate method and is ensured, that user method will be able work with data, that prepare abstract template. And if user used wrong template I expected some error, that his template doesn´t inherits abstract template.

Comment: "User can not change everything" ... man, this is open source world... Even with MVC-Entity t4 templates (for View and Controller generation)  - it was possible to include templates into your project as regular files in specific folder, reference them with VS configuration and then use/reuse them from wizard (with your changes e.g. the way they generate cshtml).